# Django inactivity timer

Tags: django, session, timer

Django 1.11.8

I have to logout users that close the browser (or tab) without waiting the expire time session (there is one limit for number of the users online).

I can't solve with SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True ,it doesn't delete the sesssion.

My idea is to add an inactivity timer on the server side for each user session, but I didn't find solutions or some examples about it.

Do you have suggestions how to implement this with django server?
Would be one a good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976498/why-doesnt-session-expire-at-browser-close-true-log-the-user-out-when-the-bro

Comment: Thank you, I know it, but It doesn't solve the question unfortunately