# Django Expire Session on Tab Close

Tags: python, django, authentication, session

I am making a  project in Django to practice authentication. I am using sessions and have enabled

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE
```

But still the session remains if I close the browser tab. It works when I quit the browser, but I wanted it expire after tab is closed. I am unable to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use jQuery to delete your session on tab close, check out reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158131/1305461). As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980634/1305461) answer states: "Closing the tab or window does not count as closing the browser. Make sure you quit the browser program to end a browser session."

Answer (score 0):

Please explain the error more in details !

In `backends.py` you will get `SESSION_CATCH` and `SESSION_KEY`
but django by default save it, u don't have to worry jut clear the migrations and again makemigrations all the tables.